# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower' in xls file

Tags: python

I receive script to run, but it doesnt work. This script sending error when he want to save results in file.

```
2019-03-05 14:16:32 - Parsing script results
```

2019-03-05 14:16:32 - Saving results to /home/Sosna/health_check/FULL_LIST_TEST.xls
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Sosna/health_check/health_check.py", line 593, in 
    process_health_check(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/Sosna/health_check/health_check.py", line 418, in process_health_check
    cell = health_check_list_worksheet.cell_value(server_row_number, server_column_number).lower().replace(' ','')
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'

Source code

```
# 7. WRITING HEALTH_CHECK .XLS FILE

print_message('Saving results to {}'.format(health_check_file))

# Writing 'Compliant' and 'Actual value' values back to .xls for each server
# Creates a copy of .xls file
health_check_copy = copy(health_check)

# Loads 'Health Checklist' worksheet from the copied .xls file
copy_health_check_list_worksheet = health_check_copy.get_sheet(health_check_worksheets.index(health_check_list_worksheet_name))

# Writes data - Server names by default start at column 9 (+ 2), row 1
for server in servers:

    # Server names are all lowercase. Also removing spaces
    cell = health_check_list_worksheet.cell_value(server_row_number, server_column_number).lower().replace(' ','')



    # If it is external hostname, we are removing domain info
    cell = cell.split('.')
    if server == str(cell[0]):
        # 'server_data' is a dict{server_name : row}
        for server_name, row in servers_data.items():
            if server_name == server:
                # 'row' is a dict{section_number:[row_number, a_column_value, b_column_value, compliant, actual_value]}
                for section_number, value in row.items():
                    copy_health_check_list_worksheet.write(value[0], server_column_number, value[3])
                    temp = server_column_number + 1
                    copy_health_check_list_worksheet.write(value[0], temp, value[4])
    server_column_number += 2

# Overwrites health_check .xls file
try:
    health_check_copy.save(health_check_file)
except Exception as e:
    print_error_message('{} file can not be modified'.format(health_check_file))
    print_block_message('[Exception]', e)
    gtfo()

write_console_output()
sys.exit(0)
```

Im totally newbie in python can you help to fix this problem ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be the script getting a number when it expects a server name in the line `cell = health_check_list_worksheet.cell_value(server_row_number, server_column_number).lower().replace(' ','')` This might be a hacky fix but forcing that number to be a string with `str()` instead will ensure that it has a `lower()` function:
`cell = str(health_check_list_worksheet.cell_value(server_row_number, server_column_number)).lower().replace(' ','')`

Comment: it might be wrong beacuse server have example name bex23Adbo2jxow and when I put "str" in excel when script try to save i have empty row with name of server

Answer (score 0):

it might be wrong beacuse server have example name bex23Adbo2jxow and when I put "str" in excel when script try to save i have empty row with name of server